# How do I get directional polylines on HERE Map API instead of solid lines

Tags: javascript, api, routes, polyline, here-api

Using HERE Map Javascript API, how do I draw directional polylines such as shown on routing result example [here](http://developer.here.com/apiexplorer/examples/api-for-js/routing/map-with-route-from-a-to-b.html)

[image]

If I use `nokia.maps.map.Polyline` as shown:

```
map.objects.add(new nokia.maps.map.Polyline(routes[0].shape));
```

I get the following:

[image]

I couldn't find a method on `polyline` to change its style.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to create the [Polyline](http://developer.here.com/docs/maps_js/#topics_api_pub/nokia.maps.map.Polyline.html) specifying the `arrows` property e.g.

```
polyline = new nokia.maps.map.Polyline(routes[0].shape,{
    pen: {
        strokeColor: "#22CA", 
        lineWidth: 5
        },
    arrows : true
});
```

You can also add `arrows` after creation using the `set()` method:

```
polyline.set("arrows", true);
```